# routing in MVC doesn't work in server, but work properly in localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess

i made a simple mvc with routing system. When i deployed it in 000webhost to be tested, all links don't work. They only shown in the URL. No error message.

i tried to change php version on the server to be the same as my php on localhost, it still didn't work

I guess maybe there's something wrong in my htaccess

here is the routing code:

```
<?php

class App
{
  // controller, method, dan parameter
  protected $controller = 'Home',
    $method = 'index',
    $params = [];

  public function __construct()
  {
    $url = $this->parseURL();

    // get controller dari url
    if (file_exists('app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')) {
      $this->controller = $url[0];
      // unset untuk menentukan param
      unset($url[0]);
    }

    // call controller
    require_once 'app/controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';
    // instansiasi class controller
    $this->controller = new $this->controller;

    // get method from url
    // check if method exist in url
    if (isset($url[1])) {
      // cek ketersediaan method pada controller
      if (method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])) {
        $this->method = $url[1];
        // unset untuk menentukan param
        unset($url[1]);
      }
    }

    // get param from url
    // check array
    if (!empty($url)) {
      $this->params = array_values($url);
    }

    // run controller and method and param if exist
    call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
  }

  public function parseURL()
  {
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
      $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
      $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
      $url = explode('/', $url);
      return $url;
    }
  }
}
```

and here's the htaccess

```
Options -Multiviews

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule !^(public/|index\.php) [NC,F]
```

Comment: Is 000webhost using Apache?

Comment: yes, they use apache as http server

Comment: Is your file named `.htaccess`?

Comment: yes, of course i named it .htaccess

Comment: The last rewrite rule will throw a syntax error. It only has a single argument, a rewrite rule requires two arguments however.